# How to remove NavigationBar border/separator in iOS13?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

So far, I've been using the following code to remove the border of my navigation bar

```
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

But since iOS13 it seems not to be working.
Can someone help me to find any solution for this matter?